# Admin Authentication Forbidden in Google App Engine (PHP Flex)

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, authorization, php-5.6

I am creating a `Google App Engine` application using PHP 5.6 in the 'Flex' environment.

I have deployed the application to GAE successfully and can see the pages when authentication is disabled.

When I attempt to add basic route authentication by updating the handlers in my `app.yaml` file to include either `login: required` or `login: admin` to specific routes, instead of being redirected to sign in as expected, I receive a `403 Forbidden` response. Even if I attempt to visit the same page in a browser other than Chrome, or with an incognito window, I still get a `403`.

### Steps Taken

1. Create the GAE Project
2. Enabling `Billing`
3. Enabling the `Google+ API` within the `API Manager` in the `Google Cloud Console`
4. Updating the `app.yaml` file to include a login-protected handler
5. Ensuring that my Google Account has `Owner` access in the `IAM & Admin` section of the `Google Cloud Console`, as per [Enforcing sign in and admin access with app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/users/#enforcing_sign_in_and_admin_access_with_if_lang_is_java_webxml_else_appyaml_endif)
6. Ensuring that the `Google authentication` setting is set to `Google Accounts API` within the `App Engine -> Settings` menu in the `Google Cloud Console`
7. Deploying the Application to GAE by using `gcloud app deploy app.yaml` from the root directory of the project on my local machine
8. Opening the project in my browser by running `gcloud app browse`
9. Verifying that the elements within my `app.yaml` file match with the [app.yaml Reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref)

### app.yaml [snipped]

```
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: index.php
    login: admin
```

Have I missed anything obvious or not-so-obvious? I can't seem to find a cause or a solution to this problem. Thanks in advance for any help you might be able to provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `login: admin` protection doesn't work with App Engine Flex:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/migrating#users